# split a large sitemap in django

Tags: django, django-models

My django app sitemap.py looks like so:

```
class DetailViewSitemap(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.8
    changefreq = 'hourly'

    def items(self):
        objs = MyApp.objects.all().distinct('slug')
        return objs
```

..and my models.py convininetlky defines the a method like so:

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    try:
        return ('detail', [self.slug])
    except:
        return None
```

Everything works fine, but I have now realized that google does not allow more than 50k links in a single sitemaps - and unfortunately I have more than 50k links.

So, my question is how can I split my sitemap so that it generated say successive sitemaps on this app? So, I would like something along the lines of:

```
http://mywebapp.com/sitemap0.xml
http://mywebapp.com/sitemap1.xml
...
```

.. if this is possible at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this was asked 6 years ago but today you can simply add a `limit`:

```py
class MovieSitemap(sitemaps.Sitemap):

    # ...

    limit = 100

   #  ...
```

Which will result in an index file and each sitemap with the limit you set:

```xml
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap-movies.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap-movies.xml?p=2</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap-movies.xml?p=3</loc>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap-movies.xml?p=4</loc>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to break the large sitemap into a group of smaller sitemaps. For instance I have built a separate sitemap for Articles by the first letter of the title. So there will be a sitemap file for every letter in the alpahabet. If you want to use alpahnumeric characters that will also work but in our case alphabet letters works fine. The Python built-in method ascii_lowercase will return an array of alphabet characters that we can loop to build each sitemaps.

```
from datetime import date
from string import ascii_lowercase
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from .models import Article

def build_sitemaps():
    sitemap = {}
    for char in ascii_lowercase:
        article_sitemap = ArticleSitemap(letter=char)
        sitemap[char] = article_sitemap
    return sitemap


class ArticleSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "never"
    priority = 0.5

    def __init__(self, letter='a'):
        self.letter = letter.lower()
        super(ArticleSitemap, self).__init__()

    def items(self):
        today = date.today()
        return Article.objects.filter(
            status=Article.PUBLISHED,
            title__istartswith=self.letter,
            ).exclude(
                publish_date__gt=today,
            ).order_by('-publish_date')
```

Below I have also added caching of the sitemaps which is really nice. Then add the sitemaps in the urls.py like so:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import views as sitemaps_views                                                                                                          
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page 

from articles.sitemaps import build_sitemaps

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', cache_page(86400)(sitemaps_views.index), {'sitemaps': build_sitemaps()}),                                                                 
    url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', cache_page(86400)(sitemaps_views.sitemap), {'sitemaps': build_sitemaps()},                                                
        name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

If you need more code snippets on how to implement it with Sitemap Index, check this post in my website https://www.ronbeltran.com/2018/11/generating-large-xml-sitemaps-django/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Also, you need to add disclosure when linking your own website. See [how not to be a spammer](/help/promotion)

Comment: // , This is definitely not spam, since the content of his link is DIRECTLY RELATED to the question. We need a *how to stop robo-flagging* link or something, I guess.

Comment: // , But also, Ronnie, can you please save us a click and copy some of the relevant parts of your page in here? Links die every day.

Comment: @NathanBasanese whether it's directly related or not, if you post a link to your own site, that post could be considered spam. Because it's relevant I flagged as NAA, not spam. Link-only rules apply either way

Comment: @NathanBasanese It is spam when you do not disclose that it's your website before having users redirect there. I think that you forgot to read the link Zoe wrote where it states _"...However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers"_

Comment: Just got back online, I should have copied the details here. But anyways thanks!

Answer (score -2):

[Create an index sitemap](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index) and Django will automatically paginate the details sitemap like this:

```
http://mywebapp.com/sitemap-details.xml
http://mywebapp.com/sitemap-details.xml?page=1
...
```